# How do I compute the coordinates of the center and the radius of a circle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$9y^2+7x^2+35=8x−2x^2−36y $$

I am having trouble with this problem, and I managed to do some of it. but I got stuck here.

My steps so far:

$$9y^2+7x^2+35-8x+2x^2+36y = -35$$

$$(9y^2 + 36y)+(9x^2 - 8x) = -35/9$$

$$(y^2 + 4y) + (x^2 - 8/9x) = -35/9$$

From Here I am stuck because I know that one of the coordinates is -2, but how do I find the x for right one for (x^2 - 8/9x)?

Center = (-2, ?)

radius = r^2 = ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to complete the square for both $x$ and $y$ to get it in the form

$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$

and that creates a circle with center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$.

We start off with
$$9x^2-8x+9y^2+36y=-35$$
Divide both sides by $9$ to get
$$x^2-\frac{8x}{9}+y^2+4y=\frac{-35}{9}$$
Then add $\dfrac{16}{81}$ to both sides to get
$$x^2-\frac{8x}{9}+\frac{16}{81}+y^2+4y=\frac{-299}{81}$$
$$\Rightarrow(x-\frac{4}{9})^2+y^2+4y=\frac{-299}{81}$$
and add $4$ to both sides to get
$$(x-\frac{4}{9})^2+y^2+4y+4=\frac{25}{81}$$
$$\Rightarrow (x-\frac{4}{9})^2+(y+2)^2=\frac{25}{81}$$
$$\Rightarrow (x-\frac{4}{9})^2+(y+2)^2=(\frac{5}{9})^2$$

Comment: I see, and I assume we square the 17/9 to get radius?

Comment: I mean square root*

Comment: No wait, is 17/9 the radius?

Comment: I tried inputting that into my online answer checker and it said it was wrong after I square rooted 17/9 o.o

Comment: I think he added wrong? because adding 16/81 to -35/9 doesn't equal -19/9

Comment: Yes, sorry. Let me change that

Comment: Thanks for clarity! Checks up!